# How to use function pointer as a constructor argument for a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I'm trying to pass a function pointer as an argument to an object that is created using a templated function, but I get this error when I try to do that:

```
error C2664: cannot convert argument 1 from
    'void (__thiscall Northland::Sword::*)(Tecs::Entity&)' to 
    'void (__cdecl *)(Tecs::Entity&)'
```

The line that originates this is this:

```
// In Sword constructor
m_entity.addComponent<Touchable>(&Sword::startTouch);
```

The addComponent<>() method is like this (non-relevant stuff omitted):

```
template<class T, class... Params)
T& addComponent(Entity& entity, Params&&... params)
{
    // ...
    // Retrieves the next free memory portion
    T* t = Pooler<T>::instance().getNext();
    // Constructs the new T - this is where MSVC points when the error happens
    t = new(t) T(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
    // ...
}
```

Finally, the Touchable class looks like this:

```
class Touchable : public Tecs::Component
{
public:
    Touchable(void(*touchFunc)(Tecs::Entity&))
      : m_touchFunc(touchFunc)
    {

    }

    void startTouch(Tecs::Entity& other)
    {
        (*m_touchFunc)(other);
    }

private:
    void(*m_touchFunc)(Tecs::Entity&);
};
```

What could be the cause of the problem here?

Comment: You don't provide an `Entity` as the first argument in the call to `addComponent`. Also, the function pointer is a member function, but `Touchable` constructor expects a normal function pointer. (They're not interchangeable.)

Comment: @leemes Sorry, I missed a piece of code there. The `Entity` calls the `addComponent` method of another class and uses itself as the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's member function pointer, not function pointer. So you should pass object too.
You can use `std::bind` for this and in Touchable use `std::function`, instead of raw function pointer.

```
m_entity.addComponent<Touchable>
(
   std::bind(&Sword::startTouch, std::ref(sword_object))
);
```